# Не удаётся вставить картинки в слайдер изображений

Tags: html, css

Хочу сделать слайдер с картинками на сайт по гайду, до этого была 1 картинка закинутая просто на бэкграунд и всё работало
(Код до:)

```
.top__cont{
min-height: 100vh;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
background:url(images/slider__images/top__img.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
margin: 30px;
}
```

Потом по гайду стал наркручивать слайдер, все изображения были вписаны в дивы в хтмл, после чего все размеры стали неконтролируемые  (width, height почему-то вообще не влияют на размер изображения)
Так вот вопрос: с помощью каких тэгов можно вставить картинку и контролировать её размеры?
Вот весь основной код со сладером:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="images/2.png" type="image/png">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;700&family=Roboto+Condensed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Fnd Upped</title>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="header-line">
                    <div class="header-logo">
                        <img src="images/111.png" alt="logo">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="navigation">
                    <div class="nav__buttons">
                        <a class="verh" href="4.html">Shop</a>
                        <a class="verh" href="photo.html">Photo</a>
                        <a class="verh" href="about.html">About</a>
                        <a class="verh" href="socials.html">Socials</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="user__nav">
                        <a class="acc__img" href="user.php">
                            <img src="images/acc.png" alt="user__account__image">
                        </a>
                        <a class="cart__img" href="cart.html">
                            <img src="images/cart.png" alt="cart__image">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="left-side">

            </div>

            <div class="content">
                <div>
                    <div class="top__cont">
                        <div class="slider">
                            <input type="radio" name="radio__btn" id="radio__1">
                            <input type="radio" name="radio__btn" id="radio__2">
                            <input type="radio" name="radio__btn" id="radio__3">
                            <input type="radio" name="radio__btn" id="radio__4">
                            <div class="slide__first">
                                <img src="images/slider__images/top__img-1.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="slide">
                                <img src="images/slider__images/top__img-2.2.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="slide">
                                <img src="images/slider__images/top__img-3.2.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="slide">
                                <img src="images/slider__images/top__img-4.2.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav__auto">
                                <div class="auto-btn1"></div>
                                <div class="auto-btn2"></div>
                                <div class="auto-btn3"></div>
                                <div class="auto-btn4"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav__manual">
                                <label for="radio__1"class="manual__btn"></label>
                                <label for="radio__2"class="manual__btn"></label>
                                <label for="radio__3"class="manual__btn"></label>
                                <label for="radio__4"class="manual__btn"></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
                <div class="str__1-cont">
                    <img class="png" src="images/m5.png">
                    <img class="mid__str-1"src="images/m6.png">
                    <img class="png" src="images/m7.png">
                </div>
                <div class="str__2-cont">
                    <img class="png" src="images/m1.png">
                    <img class="mid__str-2" src="images/m2.png">
                    <img class="png" src="images/m3.png">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="right-side">

            </div>

            <div class="footer">
                <div class="bottom">
                    <p>Introduced by D&D</p>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.header{
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    background-color: black;
}
.header-logo{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: black;
}

.header-line{
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
.navigation{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: black;
}
.nav__buttons{
    margin-left: auto;

}
.verh{
    margin-left: 50px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    transition: color 0.25s linear;
}
.verh:hover{
    color:red;
}
.user__nav{
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
    display:block;
    right: 0;
}

.left-side{
    background-image: url(images/left2.png);
}


.right-side{
    background-image: url(images/right2.png);
}


.content{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
}
.top__cont{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    margin: 30px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slider{
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
}
.slide img{
    width: 800px;
}
.png{
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.mid__str-1{
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.mid__str-2{
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.str__1-cont{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.footer{
    background-color: black;
    color: aliceblue;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
}.header{
    grid-area: header;
}
.content{
    grid-area: content;
}
.left-side{
    grid-area: left-side;
}
.right-side{
    grid-area: right-side;
}
.footer{
    grid-area: footer;
}
.container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px auto 100px;
    grid-template-rows: 300px 1fr 1fr 1fr 100px;
    height:100%;
    color: #000;
    grid-template-areas:
    "left-side header right-side"
    "left-side content right-side"
    "left-side content right-side"
    "left-side content right-side"
    "left-side footer right-side";
}
```